# RemoveAtIndex crashes playground

Tags: swift

I'm trying to remove a `Character` from a string using the `removeAtIndex` func of `String`. But it crashes the playground.

Here is the full code:

```
let string = "Some String"
let start = advance(string.startIndex, 2)
let x = string.removeAtIndex(start)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've declared `string` with a `let` which makes it *immutable*. Since you can only call `removeAtIndex` on a *mutable* `String`, you can fix this by declaring `string` with `var` instead:

```
var string = "Some String"
let start = advance(string.startIndex, 2)
let x = string.removeAtIndex(start)
```

***Note:** The above works in Xcode 6.1, but crashes the compiler in Xcode 6.0.*

For Xcode 6.0, using the global `removeAtIndex` function instead works:

```
var string = "Some String"
let start = advance(string.startIndex, 2)
let x = removeAtIndex(&string, start)
```

Comment: Nope.I made the change and yet It's crashing. Here is the error from playground. 

"An error occurred while trying to communicate with a helper application. You may need to restart Xcode before playgrounds will run again."

Comment: That's a compiler bug in Xcode 6.0. It will work in Xcode 6.1. I added a workaround for Xcode 6.0 to the answer.